# Js unit conversion

Tags: javascript

When I tried running my code the bottom half with my cm conversion seems to not work at all, anyone spot what I did wrong? I've tried many ways on how to implement the bottom and none has proven to be working. I'm a beginner programmer so my code formatting isn't perfect(i hope this clears the air) any tips on how to use HTML in correlation with Javascript?

```js
<html>
<title>Unit Converter</title>
<body>
<h2>Unit Converter</h2>
<p>Cel to Fah</p>

<p>
  <label>C</label>
  <input id="inputCelsius" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="temperatureConverter(this.value)" onchange="temperatureConverter(this.value)">
</p>
<p>F: <span id="outputFahrenheit"></span></p>

<script>
function temperatureConverter(valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  document.getElementById("outputFahrenheit").innerHTML=(valNum*1.8)+32;
  }
</script>
<p>Fah to Cel</p>

<p>
  <label>F</label>
  <input id="inputFahrenheit" type="number" placeholder="Fahrenheit" oninput="temperatureConverter(this.value)" onchange="temperatureConverter(this.value)">
</p>
<p>C: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>

<script>
function temperatureConverter(valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  document.getElementById("outputCelcius").innerHTML=(valNum-32)/1.8;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
const converter = {
  "mm": 1000,
  "cm": 100,
  "dm": 10,
  "m": 1,
  "km": 0.001,
  "mile": 3.600 / 3.937 * 1.760
};

const units = Object.keys(converter);

function convertAll(currentValue, currentUnit) {
  units.forEach((unit) => {

    if (unit !== currentUnit) {
      let input = document.getElementById(unit);
      input.value = Number(currentValue) * converter[unit] / converter[currentUnit];
    }
  })
}

units.forEach((unit) => {
  let input = document.getElementById(unit);
  input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    convertAll(this.value, this.id);
  })
})

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

</script>
<p> Type your number please </p>
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" id="mm" value="0"><span>mm</span></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="cm" value="0"><span>cm</span></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="dm" value="0"><span>dm</span></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="m" value="0"><span>m</span></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="km" value="0"><span>km</span></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="mile" value="0"><span>mile</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some messy and some faulty code, so I cleaned it up a bit. Try this:

```js
const converter = {
  "mm": 1000,
  "cm": 100,
  "dm": 10,
  "m": 1,
  "km": 0.001,
  "mile": 3.600 / 3.937 * 1.760
};

const units = Object.keys(converter);

function convertAll(currentValue, currentUnit) {
  units.forEach((unit) => {

    if (unit !== currentUnit) {
      let input = document.getElementById(unit);
      input.value = Number(currentValue) * converter[unit] / converter[currentUnit];
    }
  })
}

units.forEach((unit) => {

  let input = document.getElementById(unit);
  input.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
    convertAll(evt.target.value, evt.target.id);
  })
})

function temperatureConverter1(valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  document.getElementById("outputCelcius").innerHTML = (valNum - 32) / 1.8;
}

function temperatureConverter2(valNum) {
  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
  document.getElementById("outputFahrenheit").innerHTML = (valNum * 1.8) + 32;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul span {
  margin - left: 5 px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Unit Converter</title>

<body>
  <h2>Unit Converter</h2>
  <p>Cel to Fah</p>

  <p>
    <label>C</label>
    <input id="inputCelsius" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="temperatureConverter2(this.value)" onchange="temperatureConverter2(this.value)">
  </p>
  <p>F: <span id="outputFahrenheit"></span></p>
  <p>Fah to Cel</p>

  <p>
    <label>F</label>
    <input id="inputFahrenheit" type="number" placeholder="Fahrenheit" oninput="temperatureConverter1(this.value)" onchange="temperatureConverter1(this.value)">
  </p>
  <p>C: <span id="outputCelcius"></span></p>

  <p> Type your number please </p>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="text" id="mm" value="0"><span>mm</span></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="cm" value="0"><span>cm</span></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="dm" value="0"><span>dm</span></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="m" value="0"><span>m</span></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="km" value="0"><span>km</span></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="mile" value="0"><span>mile</span></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Just a suggestion, put all of your scripts in one file and at the end of the body. That way, any event listeners and other things depending on the DOM (basically the HTML part) will work because the actual HTML is loaded, so you would know that the error is in the JS.

Comment: It also seems like i've accidentally broke my F --> C converter

Comment: I *just* fixed that - you might need to reload.

Comment: Any tips on any future projects?

Comment: When working with similar 'listed' data like this, it might be easier to use features such as `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `forEach`, so it might be a good idea to learn those. Other than that, you're good!